# как переименовать ветку без названия в Git

Tags: git

[image: скриншот git cmd]
Как то создал ветку в Git без названия, другие ветки позже слил/удалил, осталась только эта "безымянная". Как ей можно дать название?

Comment: да, локальная. На удалённом репозитарии ничего нет, полностью локальный проект. Файл скопировать не проблема, хочется понять как проблему в принципе решать

Comment: C:\Users\nix\PycharmProjects\week3>git branch -m 97f6751 master  error: refname refs/heads/97f6751 not found fatal: Branch rename failed

Comment: Аналогично git branch -m master 97f6751. В ответ: error: refname refs/heads/master not found. Просто "git branch -m имя" пробовал, безуспешно - третья строчка на скриншоте

Comment: Ну я не помню, почитайте доку, вполне возможно, что просто имя даёте `git branch имя`.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. Опция -m была лишняя. Просто "git branch master 97f6751"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

воспроизвёл аналогичную ситуацию:

1. создал хранилище с несколькими коммитами
2. переключился на верхний коммит: `$ git checkout хэш-коммита`
3. удалил ветку `master`: `$ git branch -d master`

---

в подобной ситуации создать ветку (т.е., указатель на коммит) и сделать её текущей можно, например, такой командой:

```
$ git checkout -b имя-ветки
```

или, если требуется, чтобы ветка указывала на другой коммит (а не на тот, который в данный момент является текущим):

```
$ git checkout -b имя-ветки хэш-коммита
```

Answer (score 0):

## Давайте починим репозиторий вручную

Есть альтернативное решение. Мы можем не пользоваться командами Git, а починить всё руками. Заодно разберемся, как ветки устроены.

Каждая ветка в Git – это файл в директории `.git/refs/heads`. Имя файла — в точности имя ветки (расширения нет). В файле хранится полный хеш коммита, на который смотрит ветка.

Можно просто переименовать такой файл или создать новый.

#### 1. Cмотрим, какие коммиты есть в репозитории, находим хеш нужного

```
$ git log
```

#### 2. Получаем полный хеш и пишем его в файл

```
$ git rev-parse 195595 > .git/refs/heads/master
```

---

#### 1a. Либо просто берем хеш коммита, на который репозиторий смотрит сейчас

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD > .git/refs/heads/master
```

## Подробнее

Давайте разберем пример.

#### в репозитории есть три ветки

```
$ git branch
  bar
  foo
* master
```

#### каждой соответствует один файл

```
$ ls -1 .git/refs/heads/
bar
foo
master
```

#### ветка master смотрит на вот такой коммит

```
$ git rev-parse master
195595872372d8eee14fa8861c19e33f05cd64de
```

(у вас будет другой хеш, они довольно-таки уникальны)

#### именно его хеш записан в файле .git/refs/heads/master

```
$ cat .git/refs/heads/master
195595872372d8eee14fa8861c19e33f05cd64de
bash-4.4$
```

#### можно взять этот или любой другой хеш и записать в новый файл

```
git rev-parse HEAD > .git/refs/heads/blabla
```

#### получится новая ветка

```
bash-4.4$ git branch
  bar
  blabla
  foo
* master
```